# Logging errors from a Dashboard Widget

Tags: javascript, macos, widget, dashboard

I recently took over maintenance of a widget for OSX Dashboard. A user is complaining about a bug which I've been unable to reproduce. I've been unable to find any error logs for Dashboard Widgets, although Dashcode displays an informative 'Run Log' containing both exceptions and javascript calls to alert(). Is there any way I could send the user a version which would log such information to a file to give me some idea of where the bug lies?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to putting calls to something like this throughout your code:

```
widget.system("echo `date` 'My custom log line' >> /tmp/mydashboardwidget.log");
```

Comment: Certainly I can write log info to a file manually. However, I want to catch errors as well as log statements.